# use php to parse json data posted from another php file

Tags: php, json, post, curl

my web hosting has blocked the outward traffic so i am using a free web hosting to read data and post it to my server but the problem is that my php file receives data in the $_REQUEST variable but is not able to parse it.

```
post.php
    function postCon($pCon){
    //echo $pCon;
     $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/rss/recv.php');
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=$pCon");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
     $d=curl_exec ($ch);
     echo $d."<br />";
     curl_close ($ch);

    }
```

recv.php

```
<?php
if(!json_decode($_REQUEST['data']))
    echo "json error";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

every time it gives json error.
but echo $_REQUEST['data'] gives the correct json data.
plz help.

Comment: Also see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php to get the exact JSON error

Comment: @Pekka:itunes rss & malformed json error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not this ?

```
$posts = array('data'=>$pCon);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $posts);
```

[even the example in doc show that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

from doc

> The full data to post in a HTTP "POST" operation. To post a file, prepend a filename with @ and use the full path. This can either be passed as a **urlencoded string** like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, files thats passed to this option with the @ prefix must be in array form to work.

your existing way should work too,

is it possible that `$pCon` contains some urlencoded values such as `=, ?` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = array('data'=>$pCon);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $posts);
```

this worked.
(the person who answered this question deleted the post so i couldnt catch his name, so thankx)

edit:
there still was a small error every quote (") was changed to (\") i had a very hard time correcting this so now i am not sending data in json directly but first base64 encode it and when the page receives it , it base64 decodes it. 
now this workds flawlessly...
thankyou all...